# Is there any way to see all my approved tag wiki edits?

Tags: support, tags, edits, tag-wiki

I know how to see the count of my approved tag wiki edits, but I can't find any user interface that displays all of them:

[image]

Is there any user interface that shows the user's approved tag wiki edits?

Answer (score 3):

They will be visible in your profile (under All actions -> Revisions, and all *approved* edits are under All actions -> Suggestions – from 20k on your tag wiki edits will *automatically* be approved), but there they'll be cluttered with normal edits and tag wiki excerpts.

---

So let's resort to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) - it's a relatively easy task to write a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/591308?UserId=4281779) which gives the results.

[image]

For reference, here is the full query:

```sql
SELECT t.TagName, h.CreationDate, h.Text
  FROM PostHistory AS h
  INNER JOIN Tags AS t ON t.WikiPostId = h.PostId
  WHERE h.UserId = ##UserId:int##
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really helpful.. but i'm wondering why there's no interface for such action, when that could encourage users to edit more and do more revisions, so if any user want to improve the old edits he could find them easly.

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea why this is so, but in general tag wikis (undeservedly) don't get much attention.